# Float: None not working with Media Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working on a responsive website, and am having problems with Media Queries.

I have 2 `div`'s, side by side set at 50% `width`, with `float: left` and `float: right` assigned to them respectively. On resize, I wish to remove these `float`s and display the `div`s `width` at 100%.

This is not working however.

Here's my code;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #block-half-left, #block-half-right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
#block-full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#block-half-left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
}
#block-half-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the code itself, but its order of appearance.

First of all: You should avoid using `!important` to fix problems like this, since it is usually just a matter of being more specific on where the styling points.

**In this case, however** your Media Query is stated first, and after that you're stating the "other" part. CSS (like most languages) is read from top to bottom. If you just **move your Media Query to the bottom of your CSS**, your problem should be solved.

Comment: Simple! Thanks! I now know the importance of order :)

Comment: Great! This will probably occur again once you're mixing up more and more Media Queries with different aspects of min and max values. Max values should be on the very bottom in that case, after min values. :)

Answer (score 0):

Specificity is important in CSS.

The simplest way to increase the specificity of your non-floating blocks are to move the rules to the bottom.

E.g:

```
#block-half-left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
}

#block-half-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #block-half-left, #block-half-right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

More on specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Furthermore, you'll have a much easier time dealing with specificity in CSS if you use classes, rather than IDs. I.e. `.block` rather than `#block`.